# Sprite just keeps moving Python Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

Good day. I am using Python 3.6.5 and Pygame. You see, the thing is, that my `Mario` sprite just keeps moving up even when it shouldn't. Here's the *relevant* code:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            my_change = -2.5

        if pygame.key == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                my_change = 2.5

my += my_change
```

As I said, it just keeps on moving up, up, up, UP!

Comment: It looks like you're using `pygame.K_UP` to detect both the up and down arrows being pressed. Maybe you meant for one of them to be `pygame.K_DOWN`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to add "gravity". You can have a look around stackoverflow and there will be hundreds of similar questions.

The basic idea is that gravity is always there, you don't just add it when the keys are pressed.

You didn't post your full code, so assuming that the check you're doing is in your main loop and that you're using a standard "+ direction is low" setting, then all you have to do is always add the movement towards the bottom and reverse it only when the button is pressed.

That means something like this (again, with no full code I'm guessing a bit):

```
my_change = 2.5
running = True
while running:
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            my_change = -2.5

    if event.key == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            my_change = 2.5

    my += my_change
```

It'd probably help if you thought of your `change` as the `velocity` , so that if you give a positive velocity it will move down, if it's negative it will move up, and if it's 0 it will not move at all.

Comment: When I try this, my Pygame window stops responding.

Comment: If that's the only thing you have in your main loop, it will do nothing (there's not even the sprite showing part in there). You have to adapt this code to yours. Post the full code of your main loop and we'll see what we can do.

Answer (score 1):

Is your logic correct - KEYDOWN is when the key is pressed and KEYUP when it is released - so you would need to set change to set the direction the K_UP is the up arrow and K_DOWN is the down arrow - so maybe try something more like

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            my_change = -2.5

        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            my_change = 2.5

my += my_change
```

Comment: I want it to automatically go down when the user releases the UP key.

Answer (score 0):

change it to something like this,

```
running = True
while running:
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            my_change -= 2.5

    if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        my_change += 2.5

my += my_change
```

Comment: I want it to automatically go down when the user releases the UP key.